# Eigenvalue Problem -- prove eigenvalue for $A^2 + I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a proof I've been trying to figure out since the problem was presented to me.

We are given that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for a matrix $A$ and the vector $u$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.  The problem asks to us to prove that $\lambda^2 + 1$ is an eigenvalue for $A^2 + I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

I am not quite sure where to start.  My first instinct was to somehow manipulate $Au = \lambda u$, but I'm not quite sure what to do with it.

Any ideas for this one? It's certainly an interesting problem, in my opinion.

Comment: What happens when you apply $A^2+I$ to the vector $u$ (where $u$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$)?

Answer (score 6):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then:

$$(A^2 + I)v=A^2v + Iv = Av\lambda+v = v\lambda^2 + v = v(\lambda^2 + 1)$$

Answer (score 2):

You have $ Au = \lambda u $.

Then
\begin{align} 
&(A^2+I)u = A(Au) + Iu = A(\lambda u) + u \\[10pt]
= {} & \lambda(Au) + u = \lambda(\lambda u) + u = (\lambda^2+1) u.
\end{align}